# jQuery change page issue in Android 4.1 and 2.3.X OS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, animation

If we are passing transition attribute to $.mobile.changePage method, parent page displays twice before displaying child page. This issue occurs only in Android 4.1 device. (I tried with  Samsung s2 and samsung s3 devices).

Note: In other OS > 4.1, this issue wont occur. Animation is smooth

Comment: Maybe have a look at the replacement found in jQuery mobile 1.4 ... see: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

Comment: Even if we try with .change() method of PageContainer, same issue occurs. Now i am using jquery mobile 1.4.3 version

Comment: Is the problem reproducible on a desktop browser?

Comment: No.. This issue occurs only in Mobile android browser with Android OS 4.1 and 2.3.x